# How to use session scoped bean properly

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc, spring-aop

There are 3 classes in my Spring MVC app: a `UserDetailsInterceptor` class, an `MyAdvice` class and a `UserDetails` class (session scoped).

**What I want to accomplish** is simple:

1. `UserDetailsInterceptor` intercepts requests and set user's id in a session scoped `UserDetails` bean.
2. Later on, when the method in AOP advice class is called, retrieve user's id from the session scoped `UserDetails` bean.

**Problem** (also marked in the code below):

1. `UserDetails` object is null in `MyAdvice` class.
2. In `UserDetailsInterceptor`, `userDetails.setUserID(request.getRemoteUser());` does nothing.

**Code**:

`UserDetailsInterceptor` class:

```
public class UserDetailsInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetails userDetails;

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        //set user ID, but next line doesn't do anything for some reason (e.g. `userID` is still null)
        userDetails.setUserID(request.getRemoteUser());
        return true;
    }
}
```

`MyAdvice` class:

```
public class MyAdvice implements MethodInterceptor {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetails userDetails; //It's null

    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        //Print user ID
        System.out.println(userDetails.getID());
        return invocation.proceed();
    }
}
```

`UserDetails` class:

```
public class UserDetails {

    private String userID;

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID= userID;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return this.userID;
    }
}
```

In `dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<bean id="userDetails " class="package.UserDetails " scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

`MyPointcutAdvisor` class:

```
public class MyPointcutAdvisor implements PointcutAdvisor {

    private MyPointcut pointcut = new MyPointcut();
    private MyAdvice advice = new MyAdvice();

    @Override
    public Pointcut getPointcut() {
        return this.pointcut;
    }

    @Override
    public Advice getAdvice() {
        return this.advice;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPerInstance() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any ideas please? Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

By registering `MyAdvice` class, `userDetails` object in it is no longer null. However it is not the same object as the one in `UserDetailsInterceptor`. So the bean is not actually "session scoped"?

**Answer**:

The problem lies in following code:

```
private MyPointcut pointcut = new MyPointcut();
private MyAdvice advice = new MyAdvice();
```

Neither of them are managed by spring. As a result, things are being wired and not working the way we expected.

Comment: Where are you using the `MyAdvice` class?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It is used for intercepting any controller method mapped to an url so far (It serves as an advice of my customized Spring AOP advisor).

Comment: My question is _where_, not _how_. You seem to be creating it yourself instead of getting it as a bean from the context.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm not quite sure what you meant. I have an org.springframework.aop.PointcutAdvisor registered, this advice class is the advice of it.

Comment: Show us that configuration.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have added the config. It is registered programmatically.

Comment: I still don't see your `MyAdvice` referenced anywhere. Show us your `MyPointcutAdvisor`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It is added at the bottom of the question.

Comment: There we go. Since you are doing `MyAdvice advice = new MyAdvice();`, ie. creating it yourself, Spring cannot inject anything and the field remains `null`. You have to refactor if you want Spring to autowire the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

> `UserDetails` object is `null` in `MyAdvice` class.

is not possible if the `MyAdvice` instance is managed by Spring. You must be instantiating it yourself instead of getting it from the context.

If Spring doesn't manage the object, it can't inject anything into `@Autowired` targets, so your field remains `null`.

If Spring was managing your object, a bean, and couldn't resolve the dependency, it would throw exceptions.

Comment: Could you please explain why? Thanks

Comment: @Conan See the edit. Still my answer is based off an assumption. Correct me if I am wrong, by showing your configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It definitely make sense. If I register `MyAdvice` class as a bean in config file, does it mean it is managed by Spring then?

Comment: @Conan Yes. And if you have the appropriate `component-scan` or `annotation-config`, Spring can do its injection properly. Note that you might have to change how you do your `Advisor` registration.

Comment: By registering `MyAdvice` class to the config, UserDetails object is no longer null in MyAdvice class. thank you! However, I also noticed it is not the same object as it is in `UserDetailsInterceptor`.

Comment: @Conan Are you within the same session when checking?

Comment: Actually it is the way I create `pointcut` and `advice` in the `advisor` class that caused the problem. Neither objects are managed by Spring. Thank you for answering my questions!